# запись словаря по названию столбца

Tags: python-3.x

Есть файл csv, в котором есть название столбцов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть словарь с данными, **данные могут меняться**, как можно сопоставить ключ с названием столбца и записать в него значение ключа?

```
dict = {'Russian Federation': '991', 'Ukraine': '127', 'Belarus': '13',....}
```

Comment: уточните задачу, а то сейчас она звучит как `value = dict['Russian Federation']`

Comment: @Zhihar, так понятно?)

Comment: @vasyalulid, непонятно что вы хотите получить на выходе. А еще здесь принято приводить собственные попытки решения (даже если они нерабочие/некрасивые/etc.)

Comment: @MaxU, у меня нет решения(, на выходе хочу получить файл( например: столбец(РФ), строка А2 = 991.) Т.е мы ищем в словаре ключ, который равен названию первого столбца и записуем в него значения и т.д

Comment: вы хотите записать в excel или вас устроит csv?

Comment: @Zhihar нужно в csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как я понимаю вам необходимо вот это:

```
data = {'Russian Federation': '991', 'Ukraine': '127', 'Belarus': '13',}

keys = ';'.join(data.keys())
values = ';'.join(data.values())

with open('d:\\data.csv', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f"{keys}\n")
    file.write(f"{values}\n")
```

1. выделяем ключи, значения
2. формируем из них строки через разделитель ';' (для csv файла)
3. пишем данные в файл

Для ситуации, когда надо записать данные в соответствии с уже записанными ключами можно использовать такой код:

```
data = {'Russian Federation': '991', 'Ukraine': '127', 'Belarus': '13',}

# считать ключи
with open('d:\\data.csv', 'r') as file:
    keys = file.readline()[:-1].split(';')

# сформировать строку в соответствии с ключами
values = ';'.join([data[key] for key in keys])

# записать значения
with open('d:\\data.csv', 'a+') as file:
    file.write(f"{values}\n")
```

Comment: спасибо, но мне нужно сопоставить ключ с названием столбца, не всегда ключ в словаре будет равен названию столбца

Comment: это как или вы имеете в виду, что у вас уже csv есть и надо сначала снимать из csv 1 строку, распарсить и потом уже дописать последней строкой данные из словаря?

Comment: да. берем столбцы из csv, берем 1 столбец ищем ключ в словаре если он равен столбцу 1 записуем значение и так со всема столбцами, т.е проблема в том, что я не знаю как их сравнить столбец из ключем.

Comment: словарь может быть {'Ukraine': '127', 'Belarus': '13'}, а столбцы (RF,Ukraine, Belarus)

Comment: добавил в ответ новый код - вам это надо? судя по цифрам - это суточная смертность от ковид?